# Cnn doesnt work properly on android and makes wrong predictions

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

My trained TensorFlow Model for facial landmarks had accuracy around 96%, but when I use it in android it doesn't work properly it has really bad predictions. Even when I sent in a picture which was part of the training in python it was accurate but in android not at all.

code is my recognize image function which is supposed to transform bitmap into ByteBuffer for the CNN. I didn't do any preprocessing during training just raw image input. And labels were ints of coordinates. I suspect the problem might be here or in next function which is for loading tflite model.

This is the Bitmap that arrived to this function those 2 dots I drew in paint to show you the result of coordinates of eyes

[image]

```
Override
  public String recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    imgData.rewind();
    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        int pixel= 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputSize2; ++i) {
          for (int j = 0; j < inputSize; ++j) {
            //int pixelValue = intValues[i * inputSize2 + j];
            final int val = intValues[pixel++];
            if (isModelQuantized) {
              // Quantized model
              imgData.put((byte) ((val >> 16) & 0xFF));
              imgData.put((byte) ((val >> 8) & 0xFF));
              imgData.put((byte) (val & 0xFF));
            } else { // Float model
              imgData.putFloat(((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD*255));
              imgData.putFloat(((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD*255));
              imgData.putFloat(((((val) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD*255));
            }
          }
        }


    Object[] inputArray = {imgData};
    Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
    cords = new float[1][10];
    outputMap.put(0, cords);

    tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
```

My model visualized in Netron

[image]

The following function is function of creating a TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel in which there is function from above for processing input images.

```
 public static Detector create(
      final Context context,
      final String modelFilename,
      final String labelFilename,
      final int inputSize,
      final int inputSize2,
      final boolean isQuantized)
      throws IOException {
    final TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel d = new TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel();

    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    InputStream is = am.open(labelFilename);

    MappedByteBuffer modelFile = loadModelFile(context.getAssets(), modelFilename);
    MetadataExtractor metadata = new MetadataExtractor(modelFile);
    try (BufferedReader br =
                 new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(is))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        d.labels.add(line);
      }
    }
    d.inputSize = inputSize;
    d.inputSize2 = inputSize2;

    try {
      Interpreter.Options options = new Interpreter.Options();
      options.setNumThreads(NUM_THREADS);
      options.setUseXNNPACK(true);
      d.tfLite = new Interpreter(modelFile, options);
      d.tfLiteModel = modelFile;
      d.tfLiteOptions = options;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    d.isModelQuantized = isQuantized;
    // Pre-allocate buffers.
    int numBytesPerChannel;
    if (isQuantized) {
      numBytesPerChannel = 1; // Quantized
    } else {
      numBytesPerChannel = 4; // Floating point
    }
    d.imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * d.inputSize * d.inputSize2 * 3 * numBytesPerChannel);
    d.imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    d.intValues = new int[d.inputSize * d.inputSize2];
    d.outputLocations = new float[1][NUM_DETECTIONS][4];
    d.outputClasses = new float [1][NUM_DETECTIONS];
    d.outputScores = new float[1][NUM_DETECTIONS];
    d.numDetections = new float[1];
    return d;
  }
```

Comment: "but when I use it in android it doesn't work properly" seems to me the substance of this question. Perhaps explain and find a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I guess you want me to explain the doesnt work part. Well The input of CNN is picture 178 * 218 the output is 10 values that represent following points Left Eye Right Eye Nose Left mouth corner Right mouth corner. In Python it works very well but when I apply my neural network in Android it just doesnt have correct predictions at all. For example on the picture I added you can see the small red dots which is prediction from neural network of her Eyes other points are also totally wrong but I didnt paint them on picture. I dont know what might be the issue but I guess the function i sent.

Comment: I would like you to think about the process of putting it "in Android," by which I suspect you mean Java. Even if that were an easy step, it's obviously the part which went wrong...

Comment: Well my code of loading model in java is up there. It is pretty much same as the one from their Object Detection Example. It might be obvious that that part is wrong. But what is really wrong there to fix my problem I dont know.